# creating a dictionary from a dictionary as an iterable

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I'm working on a simple parser where order/index matters. However, each entry has many Null values, so to save space I'd like to remove them. To maintain the order/index info I'm trying to create a dictionary within a dictionary where in the key of the inner dictionary is the 'key of the outer dictionary + the index'.

It started as one long string:

```
'Blue|periwinkle|power|morning|cyan\nPurple|indigo|violet|royal|electric\nred|rogue|mauve|wine|magenta\nyellow|gold|amber|flax|mustard'
```

So I opened the file into python and broke the string apart as follows:

```
with open('example1.hl7', 'r') as message:
    for i,line in enumerate(message):
        line = line.split('|', 1)
        linekey = line[0]
        line = {linekey + str(i + 1): line[1]}
        line = {key: list(map(str, value.split('|'))) for key, value in line.items()}
```

Which gave me this:

```
{'Blue': ['periwinkle', 'power', 'morning', 'cyan'],
'Purple': ['indigo', 'violet', 'royal', 'electric'],
'red': ['rogue', 'mauve', 'wine', 'magenta'],
'yellow': ['gold', 'amber', 'flax', 'mustard']}
```

I'm thinking I need to use map() for the next part, but can't figure out what function to call to correctly format the dictionary and how to reference the outer key. I named the outer key to make it easier to call, but am still getting stuck on adding the index and making it the key for the inner dictionary. What I'm trying to end up with is:

```
{'Blue': 
    {'Blue1': 'periwinkle', 'Blue2': 'power', 'Blue3': 'morning', 'Blue4': 'cyan'},
'Purple':
    {'Purple1': 'indigo', 'Purple2': 'violet', 'Purple3': 'royal', 'Purple4': 'electric'},
'Red':
    {'Red1': 'rogue', 'Red2': 'mauve', 'Red3': 'wine', 'Red4': 'magenta'},
'Yellow':
    {'Yellow1': 'gold', 'Yellow2': 'amber', 'Yellow3': 'flax', 'Yellow4': 'mustard'}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. 
I put the *long string* in the file `example1.hl7`.

```
outer_dict = {}

with open('example1.hl7', 'r') as _file:
    line = _file.read()

for i in line.strip().split('\n'):
    values = i.split('|')
    outer_key = values[0]
    outer_dict[outer_key] = {"{}{}".format(outer_key, index+1): j
                             for index, j in enumerate(values[1:])}
print outer_dict
```

(**Note:** Assuming the *long string* format will not change)